# Python interaction with Stata

Tags: python, stata

I have a lot of Stata files where multiple columns need to be added. As many of the columns are the same, I was wondering if there was a quick way to do this in Python?

All suggestions are very much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: An exact solution requires a more specific question. In general: Loop over files --> pandas.read_stata() --> create columns --> pandas.to_stata()